# Java DOM Parser: How to get text?

Tags: java, xml, dom

i am parsing an xml document with java. I try to get the complete text from a special node.

This is my xml document

```
<xml><archi><test>asd</test></archi><brchi val="a"><asd>Hello</asd><bsd>World</bsd></brchi></xml>
```

I am parsing the document here:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new URL(url).openStream());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        // loop through each item
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("brchi"); 
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp); ...
```

That works great. But now i like to get the complete text from the element that i parse. Here "brchi". This should be the result:

```
<brchi val="a"><asd>Hello</asd><bsd>World</bsd></brchi>
```

But how can i get the text instead of parsing the elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a cleaner way, but what I've done is given the XML:

```xml
<book ISBN="0123456001">
    <title>Java For Dummies</title>
    <author>Tan Ah Teck</author>
    <category>Programming</category>
    <year>2009</year>
    <edition>7</edition>
    <price>19.99</price>
</book>
```

This is the code I've used to extract the Title text

```java
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
Element element = (Element)list.item(0)
System.out.println("\tTitle:\t"
                   + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());`
```

Comment: I dont need the NodeValue i need the complete node with all subnodes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("data.xml"));



    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("brchi");
    Node node = list.item(0);

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(source, result);


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```